# How to refresh multiple timers in widget iOS14?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm currently developing an application using `SwiftUI` and trying to make a `widget iOS 14` users can check a list of timers.

This `Widget` has multiple `Text(Data(),style: .timer)` to show some date data as timer. and when the rest of the value for the timer is over, I want to show it like this `00:00`.

So I implemented some way in `getTimeline` function referring to this article [SwiftUI iOS 14 Widget CountDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155800/swiftui-ios-14-widget-countdown)

But I don't know how can I do it the same way for multiple timers...

In the case of my code below, each timer shows the same value, because I
don't know how should I make an `entries` for `timeline` to handle in the case of multiple timers.

Is there any way to display what I want?

---

Here are the codes:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {

    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    
    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context
    }

    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        
        var timerEntities:[TimerEntity]?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntities = result
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntities: timerEntities!, duration: Date())
    }

    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        
        var timerEntities:[TimerEntity]?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntities = result
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        let currentDate = Date()
        let firstDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 300, to: currentDate)!
        
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntities: timerEntities!, duration: firstDuration)
        return completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        
        var timerEntities:[TimerEntity]?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")

        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntities = result

        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }

        let currentDate = Date()
        let duration = timerEntities?[0].duration ?? 0
        
        let firstDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(duration) - 1, to: currentDate)!
        let secondDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(duration), to: currentDate)!

        let entries: [SimpleEntry] = [
            SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, timerEntities: timerEntities!, duration: secondDuration),
            SimpleEntry(date: firstDuration, timerEntities: timerEntities!, duration: secondDuration, isDurationZero: true)
        ]

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .never)

        completion(timeline)
    }
}


struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let timerEntities:[TimerEntity]
    let duration:Date
    var isDurationZero:Bool = false
}

struct TimerWidgetEntryView : View {

    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        return (
            ForEach(entry.timerEntities){(timerEntity:TimerEntity) in
                HStack{
                    Text(timerEntity.task!)
                    if !entry.isDurationZero{
                        Text(entry.duration, style: .timer)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                    else{
                        Text("00:00")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

@main
struct TimerWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TimerWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider(context: PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)) { entry in
            TimerWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)
        }
        .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATED:**

**Types of the field in TimerEntity**

```
id: UUID
duration: Double
setDuration: Double
task: String
status: String
```

When users add `duration`, `setDurarion` also saves the same value as the `duration`.

---

**description of how timers are handled**

In the Host App, when the `duration` value that to be counted as a timer becomes 0, the `status` is set to `stoped`, and 00:00 is displayed.

And then if users tap the reset button, it returns to the value of `setDuration` and displays it, so that if a timer finishes It will not be deleted from the `CoreData`.

In the `Widget` I tried to use `isDurationZero:Bool` to detect a condition to display `00:00` instead of using `status` in the host App.

---

**`timerEntities？[0] .duration ?? 0` Does this mean these timers fire repeatedly every duration seconds?**

The timer runs every second.

As explained the field type in the `CoreData`, the `duration` type is `Double`, but Casting to `Int` type to correspond to (byAdding: .second) of Calendar.current.date () as below:

```
let firstDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(duration) - 1, to: currentDate)!
let secondDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(duration), to: currentDate)!
```

---

**UPDATED2:**

**What if your app is not running but the widget is?**

If the timer is not running in the host app, the timer in the widget will not work either (there are any start or stop buttons in the widget and all operations are done in the app).

If I don't need display `00:00` on each timer in `Widget` the code for the `Widget` is like below:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    
    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context
    }
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        
        var timerEntities:[TimerEntity]?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")

        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntities = result
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntities: timerEntities!)
    }
    
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        
        var timerEntities:[TimerEntity]?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")

        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntities = result
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntities: timerEntities!)
        return completion(entry)
    }
    
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        
        var timerEntities:[TimerEntity]?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntities = result
            
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        let entries: [SimpleEntry] = [
            SimpleEntry(date: Date(), timerEntities: timerEntities!)
        ]
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .never)
        
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let timerEntities:[TimerEntity]
}

struct TimerWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        return (
            VStack(spacing:5){
                    ForEach(0..<3){index in
                        HStack{
                            Text(entry.timerEntities[index].task ?? "")
                                .font(.title)
                            Text(entry.timerEntities[index].status ?? "")
                                .font(.footnote)
                            Spacer()
                            if entry.timerEntities[index].status ?? "" == "running"{
                                Text(durationToDate(duration: entry.timerEntities[index].duration), style: .timer)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    .font(.title)
                            }else{
                                Text(displayTimer(duration: entry.timerEntities[index].duration))
                                    .font(.title)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        )
    }
}

@main
struct TimerWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TimerWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider(context: PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)) { entry in
            TimerWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)
        }
        .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }
}

//MARK: - funcs for Widget

func durationToDate(duration:Double) -> Date{
    let dateDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(duration), to: Date())!
    return dateDuration
}

func displayTimer(duration:Double) -> String {
    let hr = Int(duration) / 3600
    let min = Int(duration) % 3600 / 60
    let sec = Int(duration) % 3600 % 60
    
    if duration > 3599{
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec)
    }else{
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec)
    }
}
```

But in this case, after each timer displays `0:00` it starts to count up based on `Text(Data(),style: .timer)` specification.(
I want to keep the display as `0:00` when the timer expires)

---

**But how can you know that the timer finished if you only store the duration?**

Until now, I've been trying a method that doesn't update Core Data directly.

I made a flag of `isDurationZero` in `SimpleEntry` to make the condition to know the timer finishes with the value of duration only.

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let timerEntity:[TimerEntity]
    let duration:Date
    var isDurationZero:Bool = false
}
```

Then `isDurationZero` will get passing `SimpleEntry` classes to `Timeline` as follows:
In the second class, `isDurationZero` becomes `True` and the timer can know the timer expiration in the widget.

```
    let currentDate = Date()
    
    let firstDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(timerEntity?.duration ?? 10 ) - 1, to: currentDate)!
    let secondDuration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(timerEntity?.duration ?? 10 ), to: currentDate)!
    
    let entries: [SimpleEntry] = [
        SimpleEntry(configuration: configuration, date: currentDate, timerEntity: timerEntity , duration: secondDuration),
        SimpleEntry(configuration: configuration, date: firstDuration, timerEntity: timerEntity , duration: secondDuration, isDurationZero: true)
    ]
    
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .never)

    completion(timeline)
```

In this code, even if the user saves only the period, the timer can know the end of it in the widget, but only one timer can be supported.

What I want to know the most about this question is how to do this for multiple timers, or what else way is possible.

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Comment: If you want to have multiple timers on a single view then yeah, you'll have to figure out when each one ends and provide a new timeline entry at that point with that timer in 0s.

Comment: I think it can be done but I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Let's say you have 5 timers, all 5 seconds apart. Then, to achieve what you want, you need to refresh the timeline several times *every 5 seconds*. I don't think that's the correct way and iOS may quickly block your Widget from updates. I'd rethink the approach / design for your widget.

Comment: If you really want to continue with your approach regardless of what I said above, please add 1) TimerEntity code (types of fields at least) 2) description of how timers are handled - if one of the timers ends what then? How is it removed from Core Data to prevent it from firing again in the future? I assume `timerEntities?[0].duration ?? 0` means that `duration` is `TimeInterval`/`Int`. Does this mean these timers fire repeatedly *every* `duration` seconds?

Comment: @pawello2222, I updated my question to make up for the missing information.
If you have any additional information you need, could you please let me know? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I understand now but I have more doubts. What if your app is not running but the widget is? Then you'd need to update Core Data entities (set `status` etc) directly from the `getTimeline`. But how can you know that the timer finished if you only store the *duration*? I think it would be better if you store the `Date` when the timer fires, not the duration which is relative.

Comment: @ pawello2222, I updated my question again, could you please check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why it's not working

I'll start by explaining why your current approach is not working as you expected.

Let's assume you're in the `getTimeline` function and you want to pass the `duration` to the entry (for this example let's assume `duration = 15`).

Currently the `duration` describes *seconds* and is *relative*. So `duration = 15` means that after 15 seconds the timer fires and should display `"00:00"`.

If you have one timer only, the approach described in [SwiftUI iOS 14 Widget CountDown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161493/8697793) will work (see also [Stopping a SwiftUI Widget's relative textfield counter when hits zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64595708/8697793)). After 15 seconds you just re-create the timeline and that's fine. Whenever you're in the `getTimeline` function you know that the timer has just finished (or is about to start) and you're in the *starting point*.

The problem starts when you have more than one timer. If `duration` is relative how do you know in which state you are when you're entering `getTimeline`? Every time you read `duration` from Core Data it will be the same value (`15 seconds`). Even if one of the timers finishes, you'll read `15 seconds` from Core Data without knowing of the timer's state. The `status` property won't help here as you can't set it to `finished` from inside the view nor pass it to `getTimeline`.

Also in your code you have:

```
let duration = timerEntities?[0].duration ?? 0
```

I assume that you if you have many timers, they can have different *durations* and more than one timer can be running at the same time. If you choose the `duration` of the first timer only, you may fail to refresh the view when faster timers are finished.

You also said:

> The timer runs every second.

But you can't do this with Widgets. They are not suited for every-second operations and simply won't refresh so often. You need to refresh the timeline when any of timers ends but no sooner.

Also, you set the timeline to run only once:

```
let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .never)
```

With the above `policy` your `getTimeline` won't be called again and your view won't be refreshed either.

Lastly, let's imagine you have several timers that fire in the span of an hour (or even a minute). Your widget has a limited number of refreshes, generally it's best to assume no more than 5 refreshes per hour. With your current approach it's possible to use the *daily* limit in *minutes* or even *seconds*.

#### How to make it work

Firstly, you need a way to know in which state your timers are when you are in the `getTimeline` function. I see two ways:

1. (Unrecommended) Store the information of timers that are about to finish in `UserDefaults` and exclude them in the next iteration (and set `status` to `finished`). This, however, is still unreliable as the timeline can theoretically be refreshed before the next refresh date (set in the `TimelineReloadPolicy`).
2. Change the `duration` to be *absolute*, not *relative*. Instead of `Double`/`Int` you can make it to be `Date`. This way you'll always now whether the timer is finished or not.

#### Demo

[image]

```
struct TimerEntity: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var task: String
    var endDate: Date
}

struct TimerEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    var timerEntities: [TimerEntity] = []
}
```

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    // simulate entities fetched from Core Data
    static let timerEntities: [TimerEntity] = [
        .init(task: "timer1", endDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 320, to: Date())!),
        .init(task: "timer2", endDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 60, to: Date())!),
        .init(task: "timer3", endDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 260, to: Date())!),
    ]

    // ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<TimerEntry>) -> Void) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let timerEntities = Self.timerEntities
        let soonestEndDate = timerEntities
            .map(\.endDate)
            .filter { $0 > currentDate }
            .min()
        let nextRefreshDate = soonestEndDate ?? Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date())!
        let entries = [
            TimerEntry(date: currentDate, timerEntities: timerEntities),
            TimerEntry(date: nextRefreshDate, timerEntities: timerEntities),
        ]
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

```
struct TimerEntryView: View {
    var entry: TimerEntry

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(entry.timerEntities) { timer in
                HStack {
                    Text(timer.task)
                    Spacer()
                    if timer.endDate > Date() {
                        Text(timer.endDate, style: .timer)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    } else {
                        Text("00:00")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**Note**

Remember that widgets are not supposed to be refreshed more often than every couple of minutes). Otherwise your widget will simply not work. That's the limitation imposed by Apple.

Currently, the only possibility to *see* the date refreshing every second is to use `style: .timer` in `Text` (other styles may work as well). This way you can refresh the widget only after the timer finishes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for explaining in great detail !!

Comment: Hi pawello, I have one case, my widget is refreshing after 20mins everyday but some time its stop refreshing and also not working on when device is locked. could you please suggest me what can I do, it is serious problem.

Comment: here is my gettimeline :-   let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 40, to: Date())!
 let timeline = Timeline( entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))